# How to center elements inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2. I have a div with some wells inside. Here is a [Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/366/embedded/result/)

My structure is

```
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
         <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3 my_span">
            <div class="well my_well">
                <h1>Text</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>More Text</p>
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 my_span">
            <div class="well my_well">
                <h1>Textr</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>More Text</p>
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span3 my_span">
            <div class="well my_well">
                <h1>Textr</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>More Text</p>
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The wells are inside a row div, how to center all the wells horizontally?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/366/) with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were describing: [Fullscreen View](http://jsfiddle.net/natalieperna/fw7dk/4/embedded/result/)

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/natalieperna/fw7dk/4/)

I modified `my_span`:

```
.my_span {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 33px;
    float: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and added:

```
.row {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

EDIT: I edited the fiddle a bit to fix the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `margin: 0 auto` to set your divs to be centered.

```
 .my_span {
     width: 300px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/367/

Comment: I'd suggest `@media (max-width: 767px) { .my_span {margin: 0 auto;} }`

Comment: THis doesnt center the divs at all?

Comment: You know what, you guys are absolutely right. My fiddle screen was small so I ended up with a vertically centered column of divs. If the OP is looking to center the row of divs, this is the entirely wrong answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
.parent-of-centered-div {
    text-align: center;
}
.centered-div {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px; /* needs fixed width */   
}
```